# nginx send log to remote syslog server

Tags: nginx, syslog-ng

I wnat to send `nginx` access log to a remote `syslog-ng` server. I installed `syslog-ng` on each side (server-client).

```
Client: 10.10.10.2
Server: 10.10.10.1
```

Some log files (messages,syslog,mail.log) are successfully sent to the server from the client, but not the `nginx` log. Server config:

```
source s_net {
   tcp(ip(0.0.0.0) port(1999)
   tls( key_file("/etc/syslog-ng/key.d/privkey.pem")
        cert_file("/etc/syslog-ng/cert.d/cacert.pem")
        peer_verify(optional-untrusted)) ); };

destination d_net_nginx_access { file("/mnt/syslog_storage/HOSTS/$HOST
/nginx.access.log"); };

filter f_nginx_access { program("nginx") };

log { source(s_net); filter(f_nginx_access); destination(d_net_nginx_access); };
```

Client config:

```
source s_src {
       system();
       internal();
};

destination tls_log {
tcp("10.10.10.1" port(1999)
tls( ca_dir("/etc/syslog-ng/ca.d")) );};

destination d_nginx_access { file("/var/log/nginx/nginx.access.log"); };

filter f_nginx { program("nginx"); };

log { source(s_src); filter(f_nginx); destination(d_nginx_access); };

# All messages send to a remote site
#
log { source(s_src); destination(tls_log); };
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: There is a nice reply on the same issue [here](http://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos/2011-March/108515.html) that should help you out.

Answer (score 2):

That functionality was once reserved to the commercial variant of nginx, but has since been included in the OS version. You can use the nginx module `ngx_http_log_module` for that.

Here's a link to the module documentation, explaining the setup and configuration:
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html

#### Usage

```
Syntax:
access_log path [format [buffer=size [flush=time]] [if=condition]];
access_log path format gzip[=level] [buffer=size] [flush=time] [if=condition];
access_log syslog:server=address[,parameter=value] [format [if=condition]];
access_log off;

Default:    
access_log logs/access.log combined;
Context:    http, server, location, if in location, limit_except
```

The 3rd form is the one you want to use:

```
access_log syslog:server=address[,parameter=value] [format [if=condition]];
```

Include the IP address of the remote server where Syslog is running.